# Style Library CSS files Editor other than SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any way we can open Style Library CSS files other than SharePoint Designer? I want to direct edit CSS file in VS Code.

Comment: Are you using a Visual Studio sloution to deploy your web parts?

Comment: if you can open the site with windows explorer, you should be able to edit any file there with any editor

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can use is to open the Style Library in Windows explorer using the `Open with Explorer` option from ribbon. You can then open the CSS files in your preferred editor. One caveat here will be that, you will have to check out the file first from the browser before updating your file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify your CSS in Visual Studio, you need to map the Style Library location to a project.  When you deploy a web part and want to link your CSS in your code, need to create a modual in your project.

If you are making a WP project:

Right click on your project in VS and add a new item

Add a new modual

Add your css file to the modual

In the elements.xml file of the modual, build your modual to reference the Syle Library Location

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="yourFolderName" Url="Style Library">
    <File Path="youFolderName\yourcss.css" Url="yourFolderName/yourcss.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

In your main C# file for your web part (ie your ascx.cs file if using a Visual WP) create the reference and render classes for your css file.

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWrtier writer)
{
    writer.write(BindStyle("/Style Library/yourFolderName/yourcss.css", true);
    base.Render(writer);
}

private string BindStyle(string StyleUrl, bool SiteCollection)
{
    if(SiteCollection)
    {
        StyleUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url, StyleUrl);
    }
    else 
    {
        StyleUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.Url, StyleUrl);
    }
    return string.Format(@"<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""{0}"" type=""text/css""/>", StyleUrl);
}
```

These functions build the relative link for you in the page and makes sure the links are built correctly to be used in the master page.  You are all set.  Now when you deploy your solution, your new CSS save will be replaced in the Style Library.  Your CSS files are now part of your solution as well.  This is the best way to modify custom CSS for web parts using Visual Studios.